# How do I fetch a properties file under a particular branch, per application, per profile, with Spring Cloud Config?

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have the following setup:

myclientapp -> myspringcloudconfigserver -> myconfiggitrepo

I'm not using bootstrap.properties in myclientapp. Instead, I'm defining the following branch override in application-prod properties:

```
cloud.config.label = master
```

And in myspringcloudconfigserver application.properties, I have:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label = dev
```

Then, under myconfiggitrepo, I have:

- master branch: myclientapp-prod.properties with `foo=masterbar`
- dev branch: myclientapp-prod.properties with `foo=devbar`

When I run the client (prod profile) and config server, and try to bind to foo in client, I'm getting devbar instead of masterbar, even though I explicitly specified cloud.config.label = master in the client.

Comment: Git itself seems to be irrelevant here: this is purely a spring-cloud configuration issue. Apparently it's not paying attention to `cloud.config.label`.

Answer (score 0):

I know of [`defaultLabel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_default_label), not `default-label`

So try and use:

```
 spring.cloud.config.server.git.defaultLabel = dev
```

And if you want to be sure to avoid falling back to `master`:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.tryMasterBranch = false
```

Comment: As a side note, why do they have differing documentation for the same feature, between https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html?

Comment: @Phillip The first one (part of the URL being served) is a way to override (with a request parameter in the URL) the second one (set at the server level)